# Oracle-Apex modal dialog display last inserted row

Tags: oracle-apex

I made page for editing and adding clients, when I click on button, I get a modal dialog with filled fields..

Also I have link on ID column which opens same dialog, where I can edit existing row.

I want to get empty fields when I click on "ADD" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ADD button set the attribute to clear cache of the modal dialog page nr.

Answer (score 1):

In your report, navigate to the ADD button definition. In the Property Editor, click Target to verify Page and Clear Cache are both set to the dialog page number.